# Compile-time checked URIs

Tags: haskell, types, ghc, template-haskell

I want to make an expression such that I have a compiletime error or a [URI](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uri-bytestring-0.2.2.1/docs/URI-ByteString.html).

```
[uri|http://stackoverflow.com|]
```

should compile, but

```
[uri|foo:/bar:\|]
```

should not.

I've come across QuasiQuotes, which are apparently for this kind of problem. However, I can't seem to create the `Q Exp` from the parsed `URI`.

```
import Language.Haskell.TH.Quote
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax
import Language.Haskell.TH
import URI.ByteString
import Data.ByteString.Char8


uri = QuasiQuoter { quoteExp = \s ->
                      let
                        uri = either (\err -> error $ show err) id (parseURI laxURIParserOptions (pack s))
                      in
                        [| uri |]
                  }
```

Doesn't compile, because it wants a `Lift` instance for `URI`. However, I'm not sure how to create one, due to the GADT nature.

```
deriving instance Lift (URIRef a)
```

Complains about no `Lift ByteString`, but I have no idea to write one. Another way would be the `Data URI`, but that fails with

```
    85   1 error           • Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘Absolute’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the instance declaration at uri-bytestring/src/URI/ByteString/Types.hs:85:1
  Expected type: c (URIRef a)
    Actual type: c (URIRef Absolute)
• In the expression: k (k (k (k (k (z URI)))))
  In a case alternative:
      ghc-prim-0.5.0.0:GHC.Types.I# 1# -> k (k (k (k (k (z URI)))))
  In the expression:
    case constrIndex c of {
      ghc-prim-0.5.0.0:GHC.Types.I# 1# -> k (k (k (k (k (z URI)))))
      _ -> k (k (k (k (z RelativeRef)))) }
  When typechecking the code for ‘gunfold’
    in a derived instance for ‘Data (URIRef a)’:
    To see the code I am typechecking, use -ddump-deriv
• Relevant bindings include
    gunfold :: (forall b r. Data b => c (b -> r) -> c r)
                -> (forall r. r -> c r) -> Constr -> c (URIRef a)
      (bound at uri-bytestring/src/URI/ByteString/Types.hs:85:1) (haskell-stack-ghc)
```

I'd prefer to use `Generics`, but I'm not sure how to use them with the QQ APIs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are almost there - the `Lift Bytestring` instance you are looking for is provided in the [`th-lift-instances`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/th-lift-instances-0.1.8/docs/Instances-TH-Lift.html) package.

```
import Instances.TH.Lift
```

Of course, you could also just copy the relevant instance instead of incurring a dependency.

```
-- ByteString
instance Lift ByteString where
  lift b = [| pack $(lift $ unpack b) |]
```

Then, with `DeriveLift`, `StandaloneDeriving`, `GADTs`, and `TemplateHaskell` turned on, you can create orphan `Lift` instances for all the types `URIRef` depends (transitively) on.

```
deriving instance Lift (URIRef a)
deriving instance Lift Authority
deriving instance Lift UserInfo
deriving instance Lift Query
deriving instance Lift Host
deriving instance Lift Port
deriving instance Lift Scheme
```

With this addition, your code now compiles. At GHCi I get the following interaction, confirming everything works.

```
ghci> :set -XQuasiQuotes
ghci> [uri|http://stackoverflow.com|]
URI {uriScheme = Scheme {schemeBS = "http"}, uriAuthority = Just (Authority {authorityUserInfo = Nothing, authorityHost = Host {hostBS = "stackoverflow.com"}, authorityPort = Nothing}), uriPath = "", uriQuery = Query {queryPairs = []}, uriFragment = Nothing}
ghci> [uri|foo:/bar:\|]

<interactive>:3:1: error:
    • Exception when trying to run compile-time code:
        MalformedPath
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at uri.hs:25:47 in main:Main
      Code: quoteExp uri "foo:/bar:\\"
    • In the quasi-quotation: [uri|foo:/bar:\|]
ghci>
```

## EDIT

Just noticed I never answered the last part of your question.

> I'd prefer to use Generics, but I'm not sure how to use them with the QQ APIs.

That won't be possible - generic programming won't let you execute arbitrary validation code at compile time. You really need `TemplateHaskell` for this. At best you could use them inside the `TemplateHaskell` code generated, but that would be unnecessary (there is nothing generic to do there).